# Is there any C-language (or even C++) OpenID library around somewhere?

Tags: c, openid

One of the  [**OpenID developers pages**](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#cplusplus)  advertises one, but that turns out to be a typo. I find none on Google.

Does anyone know of an OpenID interface library written in the C<sup>1</sup> language?

Thanks!

---

<sup>1</sup> Held by some to be archaic -- so *'70s* dontcha' know -- but there are those who love it.

Comment: OpenID's popularity seems to be fading a bit as well as it is being overtaken by other tools. Are you sure you want to use your archaic programming language to code for an archaic authentication service?

Comment: @DOK: what's archaic about C++?

Comment: @DOK: I'm sure he's got his reasons for doing things this way. It's a perfectly legitimate question, even though I myself would probably never do this.

Comment: @rubenvb Did you actually read the question? Pete is humorously referring to C (not C++) that way.

Comment: @DOK: Since I saw [this xkcd](http://xkcd.com/906/) I'm never reading footnotes again. Oh wait...

Comment: @rubenvb -- +1 for the mention of xkcd :-)

Comment: @DOK -- Thanks! If OpenID is fading, I'm glad: it's a real pita AKAICS: a hemorrhoid for André the Giant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the comment from @DOK I dug a little deeper. Both the  [**Google authentication service**](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForWebApps.html) and the  [**Yahoo! authentication service**](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-guide.html) use the  [**OAuth**](http://hueniverse.com/2007/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-i-overview/) open protocol.

Authentication -- the "API," as I called it -- looks to be implemented entirely as a series of HTTP-message interchanges with the service, so the appropriate API for a C program is  [**libcurl**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: Found your own answer, good for you. I suppose we should note in passing that SO accepts OpenID and is also a [provider](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/) for it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of one for C, but [libopkele](http://kin.klever.net/libopkele/) appears to be one such library for C++.  However, I have never used it, so I cannot vouch for it.

Answer (score 2):

ZmartZone has provided liboauth2 on GitHub.  Currently, documentation is essentially non-existent but there is contact info in the README to get help from the developers.  You can find the library here:

https://github.com/zmartzone/liboauth2

Note: This developer is the same developer that provided one of the certified Relaying Party solutions listed here:
https://openid.net/developers/certified/#RPLibs